# Adding a new row to db/model while avoiding 'collection was modified' error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

ASP MVC app.  In the controller I get 2 rows from the db, compare them and add new data as needed.  The model of each looks like this:

```
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public List<PersonAlias> AliasList { get; set; }
    public List<Identification> IDList { get; set; }
```

I am running into trouble when I get to the lists. I am good with looping through and comparing but having trouble with adding.  Here is what I have:

```
        var newRecord =
                (from p in db.Person
                 where p.ApplicantID.Equals(ApplicantId)
                 select p).First();

        //  Get the existing applicant record
        var existingRecord =
                (from e in e_db.PersonAttributes
                 where e.PersonID.Equals(PersonId)
                 select e).First();

        foreach (var newAlias in newRecord.PersonAlias)
        {
            matchesAny = true;

            List<PersonAlia> tempAlias = new List<PersonAlia>();

            if ( existingRecord.PersonAlias != null)
            {
                foreach (var oldAlias in existingRecord.PersonAlias)
                {
                    if ((oldAlias.FirstName != newAlias.FirstNameAlias) || (oldAlias.LastName != newAlias.LastNameAlias))
                    {
                        matchesAny = false;
                    }

                    if (!matchesAny)
                    {

                        tempAlias.Add(new PersonAlia
                        {
                            FirstName = newAlias.FirstNameAlias,
                            MiddleName = newAlias.MiddleNameAlias,
                            LastName = newAlias.LastNameAlias,
                            CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name,
                            CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                            ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name,
                            ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
                        });
                    }
                } // End inner foreach

                existingRecord.PersonAlias.Add(new PersonAlia
                {
                    FirstName = tempAlias.
                    MiddleName = newAlias.MiddleNameAlias,
                    LastName = newAlias.LastNameAlias,
                    CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name,
                    CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                    ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name,
                    ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
                });

            } // End outer Foreach
```

I am trying to add items to the temp list inside the list which seems ok, but I cant figure out how to move from the temp list to adding it to the existingRecord.  Once done I will add the db.savechanges();

I think I am mixing up several ways of doing this (models, linq, EF) so if someone could suggest one methoid and point me towards a good tutorial, that would be great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

probably the easiest way to accomplish this is to get all the matched records first.
Then put them into a temporary collection and then loop through that and call 
existingRecord.PersonAlias.Add.

What you are doing is indeed trying to modify a collection whilst it is being iterated over.